# How to use reverse proxy in asp.net web config

Tags: url-rewriting, subdomain, reverse-proxy

i have redirected my url But the url which i have redirected in that page nothing is showing , I am so confused and depressed now .
I have created url like a sub domain , sub domain url is creating but in that  url the page is not found error shows i am tired now . 
i think using reverse proxy i can show a data In that url

Comment: is that any one who can help me

Comment: You should put some code you've write to help us to help you

Comment: sorry, but do what @Tony says after getting an anti-depressant...(just kidding)

Comment: I have cretaed url like a sub domain.  aarti.doamin.com url is creating as sub domain , but in that url the page is not found shows .

Comment: <rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Redirect to Subdomains" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^Dazzel.aspx$" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="^FirstName=(.+)$" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="http://{C:1}.{HTTP_HOST}" appendQueryString="false" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite> this is a code by whihc i am rewriting my url as sub domain , i am succeeded to rewrite url ,but now how i'll show a particualr page in this url .